# define IP routing in linux for multicast IPs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, streaming, static-routes

I want to multicast some MPEG-TS streams on my linux server such that the streamed content just be seen on localhost and not sent to the network interface of my system (Clearly stream not routed to the external network). I want to do this for some range of multicast IPs such as 224.11.11.X. I use ubuntu 12.04. I want to know is this possible and how?

Comment: The question is unclear. You say you want to "multicast" the streams, which imply sending them to other hosts on a network, but then you say you want that "the streamed content just be seen on localhost and not sent to the network interface of my system." Isn't this a contradiction?

Comment: I want to multicast the stream to receive it by multiple transcoders on server. Because number of this transcoders are variable; I don't want to unicast stream for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

Few years late but I was looking to achieve something similar while using dvblast to stream DVB-T but restrict it to localhost to not flood my home network, and the following seem to do the trick (adjust the IP range to match yours):

```
ip route add 239.255.1.0/24 dev lo src 127.0.0.1
```

Originally found in [the dvblast mailing list](https://mailman.videolan.org/pipermail/dvblast-devel/2015-November/001579.html).